# Why is index not used when querying joined table

Tags: postgresql, index

We are using **PostgreSQL 10.21**. We have the following 2 tables:

```sql
-- testruntestgrp

CREATE TABLE fit.testruntestgrp (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    testrunconfig_id int4 NULL,
    started timestamp NULL,
    finished timestamp NULL,
    status varchar(30) NULL,
    nr_all int4 NULL,
    nr_ok int4 NULL,
    nr_err int4 NULL,
    testname varchar(256) NULL,
    usrcomment text NULL,
    iduser int4 NULL,
    muser varchar(50) NULL,
    mdate timestamp NULL,
    CONSTRAINT testruntestgrp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX testruntestgrp_ndx1 ON fit.testruntestgrp USING btree (testrunconfig_id);
CREATE INDEX testruntestgrp_ndx2 ON fit.testruntestgrp USING btree (testname);

ALTER TABLE fit.testruntestgrp ADD CONSTRAINT testruntestgrp_testrunconfig_fk FOREIGN KEY (testrunconfig_id) REFERENCES fit.testrunconfig(id);

-- testrunconfig

CREATE TABLE fit.testrunconfig (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    started timestamp NULL,
    finished timestamp NULL,
    abspath varchar(512) NULL,
    userc varchar(50) NULL,
    status varchar(30) NULL,
    nr_all int4 NULL,
    nr_ok int4 NULL,
    nr_err int4 NULL,
    emulator varchar(256) NULL,
    cpu varchar(256) NULL,
    board varchar(256) NULL,
    configfilename varchar(512) NULL,
    workspace varchar(512) NULL,
    buildnr varchar(32) NULL,
    svnrevision varchar(32) NULL,
    "comment" text NULL,
    product_id int4 NOT NULL,
    muser varchar(50) NULL,
    mdate timestamp NULL,
    CONSTRAINT testrunconfig_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX testruncfg_ndx2 ON fit.testrunconfig USING btree (svnrevision);
CREATE INDEX testrunconfig_ndx1 ON fit.testrunconfig USING btree (configfilename);
CREATE INDEX testrunconfig_product_id_idx ON fit.testrunconfig USING btree (product_id);

ALTER TABLE fit.testrunconfig ADD CONSTRAINT testrunconfig_product_id FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES fit.product(id);
```

Table `testruntestgrp` has 4507520 rows and table `testrunconfig` has 1546977 rows.

As you can see, we added an index `testrunconfig_product_id_idx` to `testrunconfig` table on `product_id` column.

However, when we run the following query, we can see that index is not used (sequential scan is used instead):

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT DISTINCT
    t.testname
FROM
    fit.testruntestgrp AS t
    LEFT JOIN fit.testrunconfig AS t0 ON t.testrunconfig_id = t0.id
WHERE
    t0.product_id = 1 AND
    t.testname NOT IN ('debugSessionInit', 'debug')
```

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
HashAggregate  (cost=383119.22..383120.10 rows=88 width=13) (actual time=9120.718..9120.798 rows=235 loops=1)                                |
  Group Key: t.testname                                                                                                                      |
  Buffers: shared hit=394 read=222173, temp read=19648 written=19586                                                                         |
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=122935.25..375057.73 rows=3224597 width=13) (actual time=2093.149..8022.800 rows=3293360 loops=1)                     |
        Hash Cond: (t.testrunconfig_id = t0.id)                                                                                              |
        Buffers: shared hit=394 read=222173, temp read=19648 written=19586                                                                   |
        ->  Seq Scan on testruntestgrp t  (cost=0.00..199813.35 rows=3225564 width=17) (actual time=0.072..2191.393 rows=3294098 loops=1)    |
              Filter: ((testname)::text <> ALL ('{debugSessionInit,debug}'::text[]))                                                         |
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1213414                                                                                                |
              Buffers: shared hit=183 read=144160                                                                                            |
        ->  Hash  (cost=97561.52..97561.52 rows=1546538 width=4) (actual time=2092.495..2092.496 rows=1546615 loops=1)                       |
              Buckets: 131072  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 2734kB                                                                             |
              Buffers: shared hit=211 read=78013, temp written=4375                                                                          |
              ->  Seq Scan on testrunconfig t0  (cost=0.00..97561.52 rows=1546538 width=4) (actual time=0.039..1663.104 rows=1546615 loops=1)|
                    Filter: (product_id = 1)                                                                                                 |
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 358                                                                                              |
                    Buffers: shared hit=211 read=78013                                                                                       |
Planning time: 0.978 ms                                                                                                                      |
Execution time: 9121.350 ms                                                                                                                  |
```

Why is `testrunconfig_product_id_idx` index not used in this query? How can we force PostgreSQL to use it?

Comment: I wouldn't be drawing any performance conclusions while testing a query on a table with two rows.

Comment: I said in my first sentence that the tables are simplified for the sake of example. Tables in production database have 4M+ rows.

Comment: Well, when asking a simplified question you probably should expect a simplified answer, no?

Comment: Then show us the execution plan (generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` for the _real_ query with the _real_ data

Comment: Note that your WHERE clause turns your outer join back into an inner join

Comment: @mustaccio How does simplicity of the tables have anything to do with the question that I am asking? I was asking why the `app_user_status_id_idx` index was not used. Would PostgreSQL behave any differently with tables having 50+ columns and 10M+ rows?

Comment: Because the number of rows in a table are taken into account by the query optimizer. If you have tiny tables with only a few rows, a Seq Scan is almost always faster than any index access.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Does that mean that query optimizer will automatically ignore the index if number of rows in the table is `<x`? Or will it use it no matter the row count, but it can result in slower queries with small number of rows?

Comment: If you have to ask the question you ask, I'm afraid you don't know what details can be omitted and what details are very relevant to the solution, so you should try to include as many details as practical.

Comment: @SamCarlson: the optimizer will choose whichever plan promises to be cheaper and thus faster. Using an index adds additional I/O requests that will make the query slower when a substantial percentage of the rows of a table are retrieved. You might want to read https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I updated the question with the actual tables and queries that I am using. I hope that you have enough data now to give a precise answer. If you need anything else, let me know.

Comment: Well, your query returns 1546615 rows from a total of 1546973 rows from the  `testrunconfig ` table - a Seq Scan **is** the fastest way to get (nearly) all rows from a table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, this was a helpful insight.